# VB .NET - Full text alignment title form at left

Tags: vb.net, forms, alignment, title

I have this code to align the form's title but I can not totally align with it, when I put a space for it to go totally left it works but it adds 3 points at the end, does anyone have any idea with fixing this?

Form FIXED SINGLE STYLE

Thank you all for the time

```
Private Sub ALINHAMENTO()

    Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    Dim startingPoint As Double = (Me.Width / 2) - (g.MeasureString(Me.Text.Trim, Me.Font).Width / 2)
    Dim widthOfASpace As Double = g.MeasureString(" ", Me.Font).Width
    Dim tmp As String = " "
    Dim tmpWidth As Double = 0

    Do
        tmp += " "
        tmpWidth += widthOfASpace
    Loop While (tmpWidth + widthOfASpace) < startingPoint

    Me.Text = Me.Text.Trim & tmp

End Sub
```

[RUNNING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aXup.png)

Solution based in idea of :  Olivier Jacot-Descombes

```
Private Sub ALINHAMENTO()

    Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    Dim startingPoint As Double = (Me.Width / 1.3) - (g.MeasureString(Me.Text.Trim, Me.Font).Width / 1)
    Dim widthOfASpace As Double = g.MeasureString(" ", Me.Font).Width
    Dim tmp As String = " "
    Dim tmpWidth As Double = 0

    Do
        tmp += " "
        tmpWidth += widthOfASpace
    Loop While (tmpWidth + widthOfASpace) < startingPoint

    Me.Text = Me.Text.Trim & tmp

End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't left the default one? Am I missing something?

Comment: `startingPoint ` seems to be calculated to center the text. A part of the window title is reserved for the minimize, maximize and close buttons and for the icon. Estimate and subtract this space from `Me.Width`.

Comment: Perfect i write this solution based in your ideia and works , ty.


    Private Sub ALINHAMENTO()

        Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
        Dim startingPoint As Double = (Me.Width / 1.3) - (g.MeasureString(Me.Text.Trim, Me.Font).Width / 1)
        Dim widthOfASpace As Double = g.MeasureString(" ", Me.Font).Width
        Dim tmp As String = " "
        Dim tmpWidth As Double = 0

        Do
            tmp += " "
            tmpWidth += widthOfASpace
        Loop While (tmpWidth + widthOfASpace) < startingPoint

        Me.Text = Me.Text.Trim & tmp

    End Sub

Comment: Where in your code did you measure the icon and the buttons in caption bar as being suggested? What happens if form doesn't have an icon or any of the buttons? Or maybe the form border style changes between *FixedSingle, fixed 3D, fixedDialog, fixedToolWindow etc*? Does it align correctly? I am just curious...

Comment: On my windows config is fixedsingle